# How to fix runtime error in Tic Tac Toe check win function

Tags: python

I'm writing a Tic-Tac-Toe game in python 2 for my CompSci class using SimpleGUI. I have a 2D array set so that whenever a player clicks within a certain area on the canvas, it will draw an X or an O in that area and will also write one of the array elements to be set to that letter. That works fine. I've defined a function to check each row of the array to check if the player has won, and it looks something like this:

```
def checkRows():
    if len(set(grid[0])) == 1:
        winner = grid[0][0]
    if len(set(grid[1])) == 1:
        winner = grid[1][0]
    if len(set(grid[2])) == 1:
        winner = grid[2][0]
```

Additionally, I have a counter that increments by one every time a square is filled and a while loop at the end that runs the checkRows function while the counter is less than 9 (because 9 is the maximum number of squares that need to be filled for one player to win). That looks something like this:

```
while counter < 9:
    checkRows()
    if winner == "X":
        frame.add_label("X wins!", 100)
    elif winner == "O":
        frame.add_label("O Wins!", 100)
```

Every time I run the code it throws a runtime error, saying "TimeLimitError: Program exceeded run time limit.", sometimes on the first, sometimes on the second line of the function. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Could you add the runtime error to the post, would help us diagnose the issue ^_^

Comment: That sounds like an error in a competitive programming session. Are you running your program on an URI judge system?

Comment: I've seen this exact sort of question before.  Is your user input code being included in the timing?  It shouldn't be, as your code is not doing anything while waiting for user input.